# How to override jQuery's use of XMLHttpRequest in $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to `addEventListener` to listen for `progress` event **before** opening the XMLHttp connection (i.e. `xhr.open()`), but the `beforeSend` method returns an xhr instance already opened. How would I override it to add the listener properly?

([Note: You need to add the event listeners before calling open() on the request.  Otherwise the progress events will not fire.](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#In_Firefox_3.5_and_later))

Answer (score 8):

You can override the `xhr` function in [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) or even on each individual `$.ajax` call. This is documented in the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs *(thanks Nick!)*.

Your code might look like this (untested) if you want to do this *all* the time:

```
(function() {
    var originalXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr; 
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        xhr: function() {
            var req = originalXhr();
            if (req) {
                // Add your progress handler
            }
            return req;
        }
    });
})();
```

...or like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ofehe5/3)) for just a particular request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "path/to/resource",
  xhr: function() {
    var req = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    if (req) {
      // Add your handler here
    }
    return req;
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, although overriding `xhr` is documented, the location of the currently-configured one (`jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr`) doesn't seem to be, so technically you're still relying on an undocumented feature by using `jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr` in your code. You just need to double-check that that's still there on each dot release, it's probably not going to move around too much (and `jQuery.ajaxSettings` is at least *mentioned* in the docs, [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)).

Comment: +1 - Just to note, it is documented, last option here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Nick Craver: I believe that he is referring to the fact that jQuery.ajaxSettings does not have its own documentation page at http://api.jquery.com/.