# update progress bar with ajax and nodejs server with express framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

i make a progress bar in a modalbox like this

```
<div class="progress progress-info">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div>
</div>
```

i change the content of a div with ajax like this

```
function download_inicio()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url:'/inicio',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
    }).done(function(web)
    {
        $('#contenido_nav_principal').fadeOut(600,function()//hide the div
        {
            $('#contenido_nav_principal').empty();// empty the div
            $('#contenido_nav_principal').html(web);//changing html 
            $('#contenido_nav_principal').fadeIn(600);// fade in the div
        });
    });
}
```

so i want to update the progress bar with the percentage of the receive data from the server...
the data is the html received from the url:/inicio

the server is on nodejs listening on

```
app.get('/inicio',routes.inicio.inicio);
```

tnx all!

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/76976/1331430

Comment: sry i read that and i cant understand how to implement in nodejs and jquery

Comment: Basically you will have to set a `Content-Length` header (with `response.writeHead`), then you will need to access the native XHR object from jqXHR to set an `onprogress` handler e.g. using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6252513/1331430) (or native XHR as in the linked answer above) then just use the code from first linked question above in the handler.